# Easy way to Copy-Paste SQL Query into R

Tags: r

I'm trying to move all my data-processes into R from SQL using `odbc` since that's where I do all my data cleaning/analysis anyways. In moving my queries to R, I haven't been able to find an easy way to just copy-paste the strings into a readable format. Say I have the following query in SQL:

```
SELECT
col1,
sum(col2) sum_col2,
col3

FROM
db.table1 t1

WHERE
col1 > 0
AND col6 BETWEEN .5 AND 1.76

GROUP BY 
col1,
col3
```

If I were to try to assign this to a `querystring` variable in R, I'd put it in a `paste`, but even then I'd have to go through and separate each line with a comma for it to pass through `getDBQuery` correctly. Has anyone found an elegant way to copy and paste SQL syntax into R that doesn't require too many fixes? Is there an option in `paste` that allows you to ignore new lines '\n', or could I create a custom function?

Thank you

Comment: It isn't clear to me why you can't just wrap your query here in quotes and pass it to `querystring`.  This is something I do often.  Perhaps an example of what you would like this to look like in R code would help.

Comment: so if wrapped the above in `paste("sql_query")`, the variable `querystring` then has all the '\n' due to the spaces. And (I believe) that's what's causing issues in my queries being passed through

Comment: I would be surprised if the `\n` is causing issues.  My queries are riddled with those. They should be getting passed as white space, to which SQL is agnostic.

Comment: I would put the SQL codes into a text config file (one file per query) and read it via `my_query_string <- readLines("my_query_file.sql")` so there is no need to change anything. Note that this may be a security issue (SQL code injection by editing the files ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As Benjamin explains in the comments, you can simply put your text in quotation marks. Example:

```
library(sqldf)

df = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5),y=c(2,2,3,3,3))
my_query = 'SELECT DISTINCT
      y FROM
      df
      where x>3'

df2 <- sqldf(my_query)
```

Comment: Ok I got it to work, I guess the frustrating thing is that you have to highlight the whole query for it to work. When I embed in a `paste` it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are also tools which generate out of plain SQL the apropriate Java,C#, VB, etc. statement. Just cut & paste.
The formatter I wrote for this purpose is SQLinForm which has several free formatter according to which environment you are working on. Link is [enter link description here](http://www.sqlinform.com)